# update mysql dentro de while en php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, while, update

Tengo una consulta que es bastante simple, básicamente estoy leyendo un codigo en el cual hay un while con alrededor de 70 iteraciones en el cual en cada iteracion se hace un update a una misma fila pero a diferente columna (mysql), este es un código viejo que esta mal creado desde el inicio.

Mi duda es: puede ser que se corte la ejecución debido a tantos updates seguidos, o que se baje la conexión con mysql o algo por el estilo debido a tantos updates consecutivos desde un mismo "cliente" digamos, por que me pasa que los usuarios guardan los datos de un form, pero resulta que cuando vuelven a entrar para verlos esos datos están vacíos o faltan algunos o cosas por el estilo.

(No necesito que me digan como mejorar el codigo, eso ya lo se, lo que necesito es que me respondan la pregunta. Gracias!!)

Les dejo el codigo para que quede mas claro:

```
$g = 0;
while ($g <= $totalInputs) // updates columns to the database table (form fields)
{
$value = ${"f".$g};
$column = 'f'.$g;
$sql = "UPDATE `applications` SET ". $column ." = ? WHERE `userid` ='".$checkid."'";
    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', nl2br($value));
        $stmt->execute();
    } else {
      printf("Errormessage: %s<br>", $mysqli->error);
    }
    $g++;
}
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Obvio que sí, al hacer muchas consultas del lado del cliente se pierde mucha información, el tiempo de respuesta del servidor no corre al igual que una plataforma, lo mas recomendable es hacer las consultas del lado del servidor. Por eso te aconsejo que hagas procedimientos almacenados.

Comment: Sí, dependiendo del tráfico en tu sitio, ejecutar tantas consultas consecutivas puede derivar en errores como los que mencionas. Ahora, si sabes cómo mejorar el código, ¿por qué no lo haces? en menos de 5 minutos puedes modificar para que se haga solo una consulta.

Comment: @Triby Gracias por la respuesta, por que estoy trabajando en una empresa y antes de mejorarlo tengo que avisar, que ya se por que ocurre ese bug para que despues me habiliten a arreglarlo, yo creo que ese bucle es la razon, muchas gracias!

Comment: Exacto, lo ideal es usar el bucle para crear la instrucción con todas las columnas y hacer una sola llamada a la base de datos. Eso, o cambiar a un stored procedure.

Comment: Cuando hay problemas de contención observarás bloqueos en MySQL, que se reflejarán en el navegador en respuestas lentas o tiempos agotados, aunque estos no significan la cancelación del DML.

Comment: Solo quisiera agregar que PHP es lenguaje de servidor por ende el cliente solo manda la ejecución de un scritp en dicho servidor, a menos que el script tenga una consulta y un update dentro de un ciclo, hay que evaluar bien la problemática por que tal vez no sea tema de conexión si no de un mal código, ademas hay que verificar si la base de datos esta en el mismo servidor PHP, Esto se debe considerar para ir descartando.

Puede verificar también en tu php.ini la opcion **max_execution_time =** que es la que limita el tiempo de ejecucion de un script.